# XCode Ionic Need A Device

Tags: ionic-framework

I don't have a apple device such as a iphone or ipad.  I'm creating Ionic apps, and it seems like I can't(?) develop/publish the app unless I have a device registered.

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use emulators on XCode, you won't "need" a real device to publish your app on AppStore... but I wouldn't recommand it ;)